# What do trivial and non-trivial solution of homogeneous equations mean in matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Suppose I have system of 3 equations
$$a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=0$$
$$a_2x+b_2y+c_2z=0$$
$$a_3x+b_3y+c_3z=0$$
and cofficient matrix $A=\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$
So I have been told that solution of this matrix will be non-trivial if $|A|=0$ and trivial in any other case. As far as I know non trivial solution means solutions is not equal to zero but in any case $x,y,z=0$ will satisfy given equations regardless of it's value of determinant. So, why do we call it "non-trivial" solution?

Comment: Since the zero solution is the "obvious" solution, hence it is called a trivial solution. Any solution which has at least one component non-zero (thereby making it a non-obvious solution) is termed as a "non-trivial" solution.

Comment: If determinant is zero, then apart from trivial solution there will be infinite number of other, non-trivial, solutions.

Comment: Precisely because they are different from the trivial solution.

Answer (score 3):

If $x=y=z=0$ then trivial solution
And if $|A|=0$ then non trivial solution that is the determinant of the coefficients of $x,y,z$ must be equal to zero for the existence of non trivial solution.
Simply if we look upon this from mathwords.com

For example, the equation $x + 5y = 0$ has the trivial solution $x = 0, y = 0.$ Nontrivial solutions include $x = 5, y = –1$ and $x = –2, y = 0.4.$

Comment: The OP knows this. He asks why, in the case $\det A \ne 0$, the null solution is called "non-trivial", given that it is trivial. Well, the question is non-sensical and it is rooted in the OP's misuse of a mathematical term.